# Record website's load time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have a website in ASP.NET using C# as the coding language.

I need to record the exact time that it takes in loading a particular page and insert that value into a database.

Say my website is hosted on net and whenever a user opens my website, I record the user's IP(or any other identification) and the exact time it took to load my website. I will be using SQL 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use a http module :

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MVC (you didn't specify), you can use the [MVC Mini Profiler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you can create a logging function that insert these data on a table and call it before and  after each event you want to measure. But that would add the overhead of the logging function to your users, so may not be a good idea.

You could also run a SQL trace and save the trace result to a table and then analyse on the SQL side the insert took by identifying the "Start" and "Complete" events

Answer (score 0):

Well what I would do, if you do not want to use a library, and keep it simple is - say that you website has a header and a footer. In the header I would create a log, and save it into a table, with a GUID that is created in the header and saved into a session. The table would have columns such as

1. ID
2. User
3. StartLoad
4. EndLoad
5. GUID

In the footer, since it is the last thing that loads onto your website, I would get the GUID from the session, and update the record to store your current time. That way each record would show the initial start time of the page load, and the end time.

Then you can add a computed column to show the seconds taken.